# how to check length of file using utl function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have some files in a source directory. I want to check the size of each file. I am using `UTL_FILE.FGETATTR` function. Can any one tell me how to use it with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE
 v_fexists      BOOLEAN;
 v_file_length  NUMBER;
 v_block_size   BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
 UTL_FILE.FGETATTR
   ('MY_DIR', 'filename.extension', v_fexists, v_file_length, v_block_size);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_file_length);
END;
```